# MP4 video on wordpress working on desktop, not on mobile devices

Tags: embed, videos, ios

I embedded a video in the following URL: https://www.speurtochten.nl/over-ons/ I made it with Premiere Pro CC, exported it as H.264.

The code I use in WordPress: `[video src="https://speurtochten.nl/sbsfilm.mp4"][/video]`

I tried uploading several dummy videos instead (http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4), and they worked perfectly fine on the desktop AND on a mobile phone.

On my iPhone, I get "Error loading this resource".